# Is there a Global variable to pull the DataBase (initial catalog) of a shared datasource

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm not tyring to set a dynamic datasource but just want to pull the Initial Catalog value from the Shared Datasource.  The values are already hardcoded into the shared DS and I could just hardcode into the field but for other purposes I'm trying to 'pull' the value from the shared DS.  I've looked around and everything want's to point me to creating dynamic but that's not the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can add `DB_NAME()` as a column to your query. This will return the current database regardless of the server. There should be an equivalent expression for other languages.

Comment: I had just figured out something similar by adding a separate DataSet `select DB_Name() from CurrentDatabase` but your way just using it in the existing query is much cleaner.  thanks!

Comment: Question though...If doing it in the existing query is it calling the DB_Name() function for each record It'll be returning or is doing a separate dataset calling it once more efficient?

Comment: I don't think it matters. It's like referencing the system date, it has that information on hand during the session.